# FolderbrowserDialog does not expand "SelectedFolder" in release build (WindowsForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I initalize the "SelectedPath" property before displaying the dialog. While this is working correctly and expands to the selected dir when running the code from visual studio directly (either debug or release), the standalone release build does not expand to any folder. Changing "RootFolder" didn't really changed anything. The code is currently targeted to .Net 4.6.2 .

Comment: Have any code that reproduces the issue? What's the value you use for "SelectedPath"? Maybe, the user doesn't have access to it.

Comment: What is the value of RootFolder? And is the SelectedPath really a subfolder of RootFolder?

Comment: @NineBerry : thanks for commenting, as I posted it was a quite dumb issue: the path simply didn't exist in the fresh release build so it couldn't be shown by default then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple (in my case):

The folder was simply not existing in the fresh release build because it is created on demand. But that is currently independent from selecting it via browser dialog. So problem is solved.